# Plotting extra linear data on D3 js graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

Check out this fiddle, using D3 and plotting a line graph against dates.

http://jsfiddle.net/T546B/172/

I want to plot some further data on my graph and want to know if its possible, I would ideally like the graph to look like below:-

[image]

The extra data is linear and doesn't have a price value and I want it to be included somewhere near the middle of the graph. The data array would be in a format along the lines of:-

```
var eventArray = [[startdate, enddate, name]];
```

I was basically wondering if this is possible, plotting two types of data, using different SVG elements on one graph.  - not sure how to approach this problem. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to set up a second line generator with the coordinates that you want for x and y